# C# Help Creating Custom Control

Tags: c#, custom-controls

Am trying to make a custom control which accepts input depending in the selected option. i want to limit the decimal point to only one so the user wont enter multiple "." how can i do this?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DT_Controls
{
    public enum Options { Any, Alphabets, Alpha_Numeric, Numeric }

    public class TextBox_Pro : TextBox
    {
        Options _Opt = 0;
        bool _Flag = false;
        int Count = 0;

        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("If set as true will accept decimal values when SetOption is Numeric")]
        public bool AcceptDecimal
        {
            get { return _Flag; }
            set { _Flag = value; }
        }

        [Category("Behavior")]
        [Description("Controls the type of value being entered into the TextBox_Pro")]
        public Options SetOption
        {
            get { return _Opt; }
            set { _Opt = value; }
        }

        public TextBox_Pro()
        {
            this.KeyPress += TextBox_Pro_KeyPress;
        }

        private void TextBox_Pro_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) == 8)
                return;
            switch (_Opt)
            {
                case Options.Numeric:
                    if (_Flag == true)
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) == 46)
                            return;
                    if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Enter Numeric Values Only");
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case Options.Alphabets:
                    if(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar)==false && Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) != 32)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Enter Only Aplhabets");
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case Options.Alpha_Numeric:
                    if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Enter Only Alphabets Or Numbers");
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

example i do not want user to enter 12.....123 i want user to enter 12.123 and after one . it should disable the flag, but when i do it it wont let me allow to enter any "." even after removing the "."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier than setting any flags is checking if your TextBox already contains any "." with the built-in function. So, replace the following code:

```
if (_Flag == true)
    if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) == 46)
        return;
```

with:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(e.KeyChar) == 46)
    {
        if (this.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
            return;
    }
```

This way you can also check for other inconsistencies, like checking if the text in the TextBox starts with a "."

Comment: Thank you very much, that totally worked :) i need that flag cause i needed a property to be set weather to allow decimals or not.

Answer (score 0):

Different cultures use different number decimal separators, so it's best to read that from the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat` rather than hardcoding a value. Because you are inheriting from `TextBox` you can override `OnKeyPress` instead of subscribing to the `KeyPress` event. The following example also automatically displays *0.* if the decimal separator is the first character.

```
[ToolboxBitmap(typeof(TextBox))]
public class TextBoxPro
    : TextBox
{
    static NumberFormatInfo       s_numberFormatInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;

    public static readonly string s_decimalSeparator = s_numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);

        if (ReadOnly)
            return;

        var keyChar   = e.KeyChar;
        var keyString = keyChar.ToString();

        if (keyString == s_decimalSeparator)
        {
            if (IsAllSelected)
            {
                e.Handled      = true;
                Text           = "0.";
                SelectionStart = 2;
            }
            else if (Text.Contains(s_decimalSeparator))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private bool IsAllSelected
    {
        get { return SelectionLength == TextLength; }
    }
}
```